# Pip & API version

Tags: python, homebrew

I have a (previously) working script which I cannot run because of some conflict between the numpy API versions... I checked to have API 9 with `sudo pip install numpy==1.8 --upgrade`, but I still get the error below. Do you know how to fix this?

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py:29: 
UserWarning: Module numpy was already imported from 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/__init__.py,
but /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages is being added to sys.path

from pkg_resources import resource_stream
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 6
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Hyperbola_search.py", line 12, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 27, in <module>
import matplotlib.colorbar
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 34, in <module>
import matplotlib.collections as collections
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/collections.py", line 27, in <module>
import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 56, in <module>
import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 19, in <module>
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 57, in <module>
from matplotlib import ft2font
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import`
```

Comment: I added `sys.path.reverse()` before `import numpy` and that seemed to fix the problem. Is there a more definitive solution?